# SAPI Speech Recognition - questions regarding PersistedBackgroundAdaptation

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, sapi

Does the value of `PersistedBackgroundAdaptation` affects all "Recognition Profiles" (those that appear in the control panel), or just the currently selected one?
And what Registry entries store its value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just the currently selected one.  It's typically stored under the reco profile token key (e.g. `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Speech\RecoProfiles\Tokens\<token ID>\<engine>\Background Adaptation`).